# Children Inside Parent that Flows Correctly upon Browser Resize?

Tags: html

**hello...**(1st time here)...

I've been told never to use *Absolute Positioning* w/ my Child divs inside the Parent.

In my designs, I almost always create a Container w/ relative positioning; & w/ a *margin: 0 auto;* so it remains centered on the page (since I almost always use background images)...& then my other blocks (nested inside the container) are always positioned absolutely...the layout of which would look something like this example:

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaTWH.png)

[btw...not a coder by a long shot...I design like a graphic illustrator would in laying out a magazine page]...but now...given the fact that I very much need to upgrade my skills (have been working in DW 2004 up to this point...just downloaded DW CC 2018, tho)...

HOW would I now code that page (using I'm assuming CSS thrown in w/ the HTML) so that it looks like that *until* the browser gets resized...& then all those elements flow correctly, stacking the way they're supposed to...WITHOUT USING THE DREADED ABSOLUTE POSITIONING...???

thanx,

**dox**

btw...not asking to have the code written for me, just a link to an informational on the web detailing exactly how to do it...thanx

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, these are very basic ideas that you would pick up from a beginner html / css course.

https://www.codecademy.com/ is a good site, and it's what I used to learn basic web design.

If you've already done something like this, I would recommend finding another more in depth course. You mention that you're not a coder, but if you're not asking someone to write the code for you, then you need to become one.

Essentially, the way to do this without "absolute" is with margin. For example, `margin-left: 80px;`

Comment: Moby Action...thanx!...could you please give me one quick example (based on my example design) of a margin snippet & where/how it gets placed (& I'm assuming it goes into the nested div content, but I'm wondering: does the positioning then change to 'relative'?)...thanx again, dox

Comment: Yes the example would be very simple - in the css for the div, you can put 'margin-left: 40px;' and this will give the desired effect. The positioning doesn't change to relative automatically, you would do this with 'position: relative;'